# Conditional expectation of Binomial variable

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\ X \sim U(70,100) $ be a discrete distribution such that $\ P\{X=i\} = \frac{1}{31} $ and $\ Y \sim B(i,0.75) $

What is the $\ E[Y] $ ?

I don't understand the solution which is

$\ E[Y] = E[E[Y|X]] = E[0.75X] = 0.75E[X] = 0.75 \cdot \frac{100+70}{2} = 63.75$

I don't understand how to get to this answer. I try:

$$\ E[Y] = E[E[Y|X]] = \sum_x E[Y| X=x] \cdot P\{X=x\}  = \sum_x y \cdot P\{Y=y, X=x\} =\\ \sum_x y \cdot P\{Y=y\}\cdot P\{X=x\} = y \cdot P\{Y=y\} \cdot \sum_x P\{X=x\} = y \cdot P\{Y=y\} $$

Comment: Your first line makes no sense. Did you mean to say "A random pair $(X, Y)$ is distributed in such a way that $X \sim \mathrm{Unif}(70, 100)$ and given $X = i,$ $Y \sim \mathrm{Bin}(i, 3/5)$"?

Comment: Anyway, remember that the expectation of binomial $(n, p)$ is $np,$ thus, the expectation of $Y$ given $X$ is $3/4X.$

Comment: Yes, correct that is what I meant. Thanks. Could you also explain to me why $\ E[XY|X] = XE[Y|X] $ ? I'm trying to find $\ E[XY] $. I'm talking about those two $\ X, Y $ mentioned above.

Comment: I am not sure if you know measure theory or not, but intuitively, given $X,$ we know handle it as a deterministic quantity, hence $XY$ given $X$ is like $cY$ and so $E(cY) = cE(Y).$

Comment: Oh that’s because $\ X \ is like a parameter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer started true but continued wrong! Hence your answer, we can write:$$E[Y] {= E[E[Y|X]] \\= \sum_x E[Y| X=x] \cdot P\{X=x\}\\=\sum_x E[Y| X=x] \cdot {1\over 31}\\=\sum_{x=70}^{100} 0.75\cdot x \cdot {1\over 31}\\={3\over 124}\sum_{x=70}^{100}x\\.\\.\\.\\=63.75}$$